# How to make connection with remote server using pystunnel

Tags: remote-access, stunnel, remote-connection

I want to create a connection with a remote server using stunnel. I have IP address of the remote system along with port.

I want to use pystunnel library to make connection in a python script.

I did not get any reference to make a connection between two servers. Kindly help me.

Comment: I found quite many examples with a simple google search. Is this not helping you? https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html#EXAMPLES

Answer (score 0):

> I have IP address of the remote system along with port.

Is it local IP or public IP?

Comment: It is a public IP